# Find destination URL using cURL

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I'm trying to get the destination url by using cURL.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://www.cnn.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.mydomain.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The above code produces the following outputs, and it's working fine in my local server.

Output : "http://edition.cnn.com" in local server, and "http://www.cnn.com" in actual server.

```
------------------------------------------------------
                    Server Detail
------------------------------------------------------
Local                    |            Actual
                         |
PHP Version 5.3.13       |      PHP Version 5.3.20
cURL Info 7.24.0         |      cURL Info 7.15.5

Protocols:      
dict, file, ftp,         |      telnet, dict,
ftps, gopher,            |      ldap, http,
http, https,             |      file, https, ftps
imap, imaps, ldap,       |      tftp,ftp,
pop3, pop3s,             |
rtsp, scp,               |
sftp, smtp,              |
smtps,                   |
telnet, tftp             |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Why there is a problem in actual server?

Comment: perhaps website have stored some informations like personnal IP or others and redirect you

Answer (score 0):

> Why there is a problem in actual server?

My guess is CNN are using headers or IP to show different content.

Try the Firefox plugin HTTP live headers to see what your browser does, and copy that in CURL.